# 'missing argument: passed to contract', Token Deploy ERC20

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Im trying to create a Token Generator(Token Factory). I dont know how to include the function create in the deploy script. When I excluded

> const tx

I deployed a token without name, symbol, decimals and totalSupply but cant deploy a token with name, symbol, decimals and totalSupply.

Here's my contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "./TokenFactoryBase.sol";
import "../interfaces/IStandardERC20.sol";

contract StandardTokenFactory is TokenFactoryBase {
  using Address for address payable;
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  constructor(address factoryManager_, address implementation_) TokenFactoryBase(factoryManager_, implementation_) {}

  function create(
    string memory name, 
    string memory symbol, 
    uint8 decimals, 
    uint256 totalSupply
  ) external payable enoughFee nonReentrant returns (address token) {
    refundExcessiveFee();
    payable(feeTo).sendValue(flatFee);
    token = Clones.clone(implementation);
    IStandardERC20(token).initialize(msg.sender, name, symbol, decimals, totalSupply);
    assignTokenToOwner(msg.sender, token, 0);
    emit TokenCreated(msg.sender, token, 0);
  }
}
```

Here's my deploy.

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const StandardTokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("StandardTokenFactory");

 // const token = await StandardTokenFactory
  const token = await StandardTokenFactory.deploy("0x4D21ED77b4Fc2Df4f4186fc8170FBdDe4b196A51","0x4D21ED77b4Fc2Df4f4186fc8170FBdDe4b196A51");


  await token.deployed();
  
  const tx = await token.create({
         address: "0x4D21ED77b4Fc2Df4f4186fc8170FBdDe4b196A51", 
         name_: "RNCHEY", 
         symbol_:"RNCH", 
         decimals_: "18", 
         totalSupply_: "100000"
  })

  await tx.wait();

  console.log("Token deployed to:", token.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Terminal output:

```
Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=1, expectedCount=4, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

Guys I'm new to programming and would be very grateful if someone helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  const tx = await token.create(
         "RNCHEY", 
         "RNCH", 
         "18", 
         "100000"
  )
```

Basically the arguments must be separated and not in a single structure.